# create a file in each subdirectory and write its path into it

Tags: command-line, find, xargs

I'm studying Linux and I've found an interesting exercise. Create a number of directories in `~` (`abc`, `abc/def`, `abc/xyz`, `abc/def/ghi/123`, `abc/def/ghi/456`), which is an easy task. After that create a file called `1.txt` in `abc` and each of its subdirectories, writing the path of the files to them (for example `~/abc/def/1.txt` should contain its path inside itself).

I used `find /home/alex/abc -exec touch {}/1.txt \;` which tried creating `home/alex/DIRECTORY/1.txt/1.txt` for each of the subdirectories, though, hopefully, creating the `1.txt` files I need, but it's still incorrect behavior and therefore not good.

The bigger problem is writing file path to each of these `1.txt`. I can use `find /home/alex/abc -name 1.txt` to locate each of them but I have no idea how to write each separate line to each separate file. I've been trying to do it with `-exec` and `xargs` but nothing worked at all.

So, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already made the directories, then do:

```
find ~/abc -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "$1"/1.txt > "$1"/1.txt' _ {} \;
```

This runs `sh -c 'echo "$1"/1.txt > "$1"/1.txt'` for each directory (and only directories, because of `-type d`), with `_` and the path to the directory as arguments. Then `echo "$1"/1.txt > "$1"/1.txt` outputs the path + `1.txt` to a file named the same. This will also create the files as needed.

Comment: 'echo "$1"/1.txt' -- this one is correct. Your one echoes "/directory.txt", but it should be "/directory/1.txt". Nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: @AlexF ah, sorry. Too many 1s.